# AngularJS Conditionally Remove CSS Hover

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to remove the :hover from a css inline in angular without removing the whole class?

Like the following removes the whole class:

```
ng-class="{'option-selected' : option.chosen}"
```

But say `option-selected` had a `option-selected:hover`

Is there a way to remove :hover inline within the ng-class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attach the hover to another class that you can toggle.

Somethign like

```
ng-class="{'option-selected': option.chosen, 'option-hover': option.hover }
```

Then in your css for when setting up the hover you would have

```
.option-selected.option-hover:hover{
    ...
}
```

That way, the only way the hover will work is if both classes are on it.

Besides that, no there is no way to get around the hover from css unless you start dropping in !important's everywhere.

Comment: Or the op could just add an id to the specific element and use `#id:hover`. Anything with a more specific CSS selector could be used to override.

Comment: Maybe does not help you but know that there is also this directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover